# Tkinter: How to print text into a Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have something like an e-mail storage and I want that the saved information printed out in my `Label`, **but** I want that the information stacked among each other.

This is my code, but when I enter another e-mail and password, the current `Label` text is replaced.

How can I fix that?

```
def print_data(mail,passwort):
    label_list["text"] = str(mail)+" | "+str(passwort)

def save_info():
    mail = entry_mail.get()
    passwort = entry_passwort.get()
    entry_mail.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_passwort.delete(0, tk.END)
    print_data(mail,passwort)
```

Comment: For your case, better use a `Text` widget instead of `Label`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to store the previous information in a variable. Then
use:

```
label.configure(text= "previous label" + "new text")
```

Comment: @CoolCloud You should not modify other's posted code.  You can add another answer instead. Also your change have same issue as OP.